# Identifying neutral and ground in breaker box

Tags: circuit-breaker

Short version: In this breaker box to install a 14-50R would I run both ground and neutral to the same bus bar on the right?

[image: Outdoor breaker box directly beneath meter]

Long version: This breaker box is directly beneath the meter outdoors in a modular home I purchased. I'm wiring an outdoor 14-50R receptacle into the existing 50 amp breaker in the photo and so far as I can tell I'll be tying the ground and neutral to the same bus bar on the right side of the picture. I know I should consult a licensed electrician and electricity is dangerous, just looking for a relatively simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is your main panel so having your grounded and grounding conductor on the same buss is the right thing to do here.
Grounded I’d the neutral , grounding is the bare copper or green. Note they could be on separate busses but the proper bonding jumper would be required.

Comment: Note that you may not have a lug on that Neutral / Ground bar big enough for your Neutral wire on the 50A circuit, meaning you may need to replace that bar with one that has more larger lugs on it. It might be possible though that the largest ground wire, on the topmost lug, can fit into one of the other holes, allowing you to use that lug for your 50A circuit neutral.

Comment: Most busses do have a listing 14 thru 6 awg in panels. Or add a screw in lug just like the top ones.